# Database output to EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext, android-cursor

i want to retrieve id from database where name = saqib into the EditText(textbox) in android, i have tried different ways but can't achieve my desired output instead of that the given output will be shown every time. [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cylFe.png)

onButtonClick:

```
    final EditText i=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.id_etxt);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Cursor res= mydatabase.fet();
            i.setText(res.toString());


        }
    });
```

Database.java class

```
public Cursor fet(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("select ID from record where Name=?",new String[] {"saqib"});
    return res;
}
```

Comment: i have tried your solution but can't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cursor res = mydatabase.fet();
if (res.getCount() > 0) {
    res.moveToFirst();
    i.setText(res.getString(0));
} else {
    throw new SQLiteException("e");
}
```

Comment: Please describe, what was the problem and how will this code solve it, to help others understand this answer

Comment: Once a cursor has been returned from a database query, an app needs to iterate over the result set and read the column data from the cursor. While Reading any rows of data can be read from the cursor, the position must be moved to point to a valid row of data.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you set the whole `Cursor` as String in `EditText`, which is not right way to set **ID**.

You have to extract the **ID** from `Cursor` like below to use it in `EditText`:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Cursor res = mydatabase.fet();

    if(res != null && res.moveToFirst()) {
        String id = Integer.toString(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex("ID")));
        i.setText(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: application has stoped.

Comment: **ID** is String or int?